# js document sort not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to earn JavaScript and i am following Michael Moncur JavaScript in 24Hr 4th edition. One of the examples in the book is below which is suppose to sort an array of names into order. But when i click on the button nothing is happening. Is the code correct or is the book out of date.

HTML file named sort.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Array Sorting Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="sort.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sorting String Arrays</h1>
<p>Enter two or more names in the field below,
and the sorted list of names will appear in the
text area.</p>
<form name="theform">
Name:
<input type="text" name="newname" size="20">
<input type="button" name="addname" value="Add"
onclick = "SortNames();">
<br>
<h2>Sorted Names</h2>
<textarea cols="60" rows="10" name = "sorted">
The sorted names will appear here.
</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the JS file names sort.js

```js
// initialize the counter and the array
var numnames=0;
var names = new Array();
function SortNames() {
// Get the name from the text field
thename=document.theform.newname.value;
// Add the name to the array
names[numnames]=thename;
// Increment the counter
numnames++;
// Sort the array
names.sort();
document.theform.sorted.value=names.join(“\n”);
}
```

Any ideas whats wrong

Comment: learning sth in 24Hrs, most likely leads to only making things that need 24Hrs tops, nothing else, except, of course, if you learn with the **speed of light**  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.theform.sorted.value=names.join("\n");
```

The problem is that you're using typographic doble quotes.

If you replace `“` with `"` will work.

Comment: great thanks I missed this one. I did the HTML doc but forgot the JS one.

Comment: If You found helpful this answer please accept this answer. Thanks!